# MySQL storage : best way to archive data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quiet new in the SQL field. Thus I have a way of working question.

Every week, I will send data from an Excel spreadsheet on my MySQL DB through a pHp code. This is already working. Thus I have a table which I can update.

Actually I'm sending price of a specific underlying on my DB. What is the best way to archive my data as following.

On my DB, I have the below structure :

```
tabe t_index
Label = VARCHAR(255)
Price = float
Date = date()
```

Let's say I sent my data on my db last week, thus I stored :

```
Stock A
102.85
2013-03-18
```

Today, I want to send new price for the same `Stock A` which is `103.54`, but I would like to archive and keep the `102.85` price to be able to make some return or whatever between the two prices.

How should I proceed ?

I hope my question is not too messy... 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this is, create a UPDATE trigger which inserts old value in another table. So when you update an existing entry, old data will be copied/archived to another table.

```
CREATE TABLE t_index_archive (
Label VARCHAR(255),
Price float,
Date datetime);
```

Now create a trigger on your existing table

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS archive_t_index;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER archive_t_index BEFORE UPDATE ON t_index
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO t_index_archive VALUES (OLD.Label, OLD.Price, OLD.Date);
     END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: can't we do it in the same table by adding one flag cloumn?

Comment: There are lot many different approaches to do the same. Here question is for archiving the data, that means, this data is required only for historical purpose and will not be used to display in real time. Also, if we keep old data in the table, it will increase the table scan when lot of data accumulated in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column named like `is_active` ENUM type with value `active,inactive`

By default `is_active`'s value will be `'active'`

and when you enter new entry in database just update old entry's `is_active` with `'inactive'` and then add new entry

Fetch new data using query using where clause `WHERE is_active='active'`